# How to stay logged in using cookie in Laravel for manual login system?

Tags: php, laravel-5, cookies, authentication

Here is my code for login check.how can i put cookie value to stay logged in for specific time.

```
   /*--------------- Check Login -----------------*/
public function checkLogin(Request $request){
    $email=$request->email;
    $password=md5($request->password);
   $remember_me = $request->has('remember_me') ? true : false; 
    $result=DB::table('admins')->where('email_address',$email)->where('password',$password)->where('access_label',3)->where('activation_status',1)->first();

    if($result){
        Session::put('frontend_name', $result->admin_name);
        Session::put('frontend_id', $result->admin_id);
        Session::put('frontend_label',$result->access_label);

        return Redirect::to('/'); 
    }else {
        Session::put('exception', 'Invalid Login Detail...!!!');

        return Redirect::to('frontend-login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Laravel already have it . Please go though the documentation 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#remembering-users